# Can't put data-toggle="modal" inside submit tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

This time I'm working form submit & I want to load bootstrap model when click that submit button. I working with inteliJ idea & It says Attribute data-toggle is not allowed here & Attribute data-target is not allowed here with in the submit tag.This is my code.. What can I use instead of 
`<s:submit cssClass="btn btn-primary"`

```
<head>
    <script>
        function add() {
        var lookupType = document.getElementById("lookupType");
        var typeID = -1;
        if (lookupType != null) typeID = lookupType.value;
        document.forms[0].action = "ManageLookupSupport!add.action?" + encodeURI("keyValue.keyType=" + typeID);
        document.forms[0].submit();
         }
    </script>
</head>

<div class="container-fluid" id="page">
   <div id="page-wrapper">
      <s:form theme="simple">
         <div class="panel-body" align="center">
            <s:submit cssClass="btn btn-primary" value="Add"
                onclick="javascript:add();return false" 
                data-toggle="modal" data-target="#lookupModal"/>                      
         </div>
      </s:form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If it says, that it is not allowed, then it probably isn't.

Comment: If you don't want the form to submit....don't use a submit button and use a button with `type="button"`

Comment: @charlietfl  when i use type button what shoud I put instead of document.forms[0].action = "ManageLookupSupport!add.action?" + encodeURI("keyValue.keyType=" + typeID);
        document.forms[0].submit();

Comment: You don't need to modify the action if you do trigger submit and you have named inputs in the form